# How DateRangeSlider in bokeh works?

Tags: bokeh, daterangepicker

I have been trying to work with dates in bokeh, but couldn't find a way, then I came across DateRangeSlider in bokeh but donot know the syntax how to initialze and use it. I need help in the working of DateRangeSlider in bokeh! Need Examples with code.

Answer (score 9):

```
from datetime import date

from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout

from bokeh.io import curdoc

date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", start=date(2017, 1, 1), end=date.today(), value=(date(2017, 9, 7), date(2017, 10, 15)), step=1)


l = layout(children=[[date_range_slider]], sizing_mode='fixed')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "DateRangeSlider Example"
```

This should create a date range slider from Jan 1st 2017 to today (17th Oct 2017, in this case)

Below are the screenshots of this example:

Date Range Slider with the chosen default range
[image: Date Range Slider with the chosen default range]

Date Range Slider with full range
[image: Date Range Slider with full range]

For some reason, the start date sets to 01/01/2016 even though the specified value is 01/01/2017. When I set it to 2nd Jan, the year changes to 2017. I guess this is a bug.

EDIT: Works as expected in the latest version of bokeh.

Comment: This was a bug in older releases that is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem, I'm able to deal with dates. Guess how? not with DateRangeSlider! I have these dates in the form of strings in the pandas dateframe. e.g `lookup = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=',')`.
 I am taking input for "from" and "to" dates to be searched for via. TextInput, then I'm converting all of the  date strings and input strings to "pandas.tslib.Timestamp" objects using `to_datetime()` function e.g `lookup.Created_Date=pd.to_datetime(lookup['Created_Date'])`
where lookup is my pandas dataframe. Then I'm able to compare and render required outputs :D.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slider in the newer bokeh versions called `DateSlider` which does what you want. 
In the example of @Aarvi its

```
date_slider = DateSlider(title="Date Range: ", start=date(2017, 1, 1), end=date.today(), value=date(2017, 9, 7), step=1)
```